# Trouble getting Conditional CSS for iOS devices to work

Tags: ios, css, formatting, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I'm having some trouble with "conditional" CSS for iOS devices. Here is the source I currently have... take note of the two linked stylesheets. If it's not clear, I want the mobile.css file used if it's an iPhone/iPod Touch device and style.css otherwise. I'm getting weird instances where some portions of CSS tags are being pulled from one CSS file and other tags from another.

For example, I want a different header displayed depending on which platform. I have a #header{} section in mobile.css and a #header{} section in style.css both of which have their own background-images. Things work fine on a non-mobile device, but when I load the page on my iPod Touch, I get the image from the style.css but with the width/height from mobile.css (thus crops/cuts off the image). What could I be doing wrong? Both CSS files validated fine.

Thanks in advance! (in case it's of any relevance, this is all through Grails)

```
<html>
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <title>Home</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" > 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" > 
        <meta name="layout" content="main"> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="header"></div>
        <p>Test</p>
<body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
#header {
    background-image: url('../images/casmlogo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 20px;  

}
```

mobile.css

```
#header {
    background-image: url('../images/logo-apple.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: can you post the CSS for #header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iOS device will load both stylesheets in this case. 
Just put the mobile.css link beneath the normal style.css and thing will be a lot better.
The rules in mobile.css will then override the rules from style.css